# Has touchpad-indicator been fixed?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I have been using Ubuntu since 11.04.  Is touchpad-indicator already fixed in 11.10? Otherwise, does anyone know if it is working in Xubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

It works.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error message, but it DOES work...the error message is just annoying. ERROR MESSAGE:
Error while trying to run (/usr/share/touchpad-indicator/change_touchpad_state.py)
which is linked to the key (<Control><Alt>z)

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/keybindings/touchpad_indicator/binding ""
```